# replace ’ with javascript (not ' )

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, expression

i'm having a problem replacing ==> `’` (apostrophe) with a space i know it looks so easy but what i mean is editors don't type apostrophe like this ==> `’`   but like this ==> `'` and i can't find a way to replace it using

```
var newtext = old.replace(/'/g,"");
```

here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/zYK9f/4/
in this example you can type ==> `’` in the page but not in the code editor tried a lot but no result hope you can help
thanks
***sorry i mean apostrophe not semicolon***

Comment: That looks like an apostrophe to me...

Comment: What kind of "editors" are you referring to and why is that a problem?

Comment: I think I've encountered something similar in the past...he may be referring to text that's copied from Microsoft Word that contains either an apostrophe or a quote. MS Word annoyingly replaces these symbols with something fancier, which may not be interpreted well when pasted into other text editors.

Comment: Just FYI (and WolframAlpha backs me up on this): the former character is a [right-single-quote](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%80%99), and the latter is an [apostrophe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%27). Different things.

Comment: FYI: The "other apostrophe" is a "Right Single Quotation Mark": http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Comment: @danyim: They're both just characters, if your "editor" can't take anything outside 7-bit ASCII, it might be time to get a new one.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Sure, but does your keyboard have both characters?  Mine certainly doesn't.

Comment: i'm using dreamweaver thanks all i used /\u2019/ instead of /'/ and now it's working thanks all

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Well, try writing a line of code that involves apostrophes or quotes in Word, paste that into your normal code editor, and then try to compile it. If you didn't know about this issue beforehand, you'd be hard-pressed to figure out what exactly is throwing the wrench into your failed build...

Comment: @danyim: Why would anybody in their right mind write code into Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for... like the other answers suggested, you can use

```
var newtext = old.replace(/'|’/g," ");
```

However, if the character `’` isn't allowed in your editor, you can use the unicode equivalent:

```
var newtext = old.replace(/\u2019/g," ");
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Unicode literals. However, the OP wants to substitute quotation marks with a space, not an empty string; also, the second alternative you propose contains a syntax error (missing a comma between the two arguments of `replace`) and is not equivalent to the first (missing `'` in the regular expression).

Comment: i'm using dreamweaver thanks all i used /\u2019/ instead of /'/ and now it's working thanks all

Answer (score 7):

Just copy and paste the character to account for both:

```
var newtext = old.replace(/'|’/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var old = "you’ll keep’’’ finding more and ''''more ways to use it.";
var newtext = old.replace(/’/g,"");
var newtext = newtext.replace(/'/g,"");
$("#text").html(newtext);
```

Will get rid of both types of apostrophes. Is this what you want?

Comment: the problem is dreamweaver can't deal with ’  just ' i don't know if it's blind

Comment: try using "&#0146;". That's the HTML code for the curly apostrophe.